# How install apcu as php7 extension on debian

Tags: debian, apc, php-7

I have seen this tutorial for ubuntu.
    http://thereluctantdeveloper.com/2015/12/quick-and-dirty-php-70-set-up-on-ubuntu-1404-with-apcu

It's not clear for me after step(git clone).
I need apcu extension for my app to perform faster.
Please guide to install apcu extension for php 7 on debian.

Comment: Have you installed the compiled extension? https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-php-apcu-extension.html or http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Comment: In severpilot.io,I got "pecl7.0-sp not found".In PHP.net,It is for php5.

Comment: Methods for PECL extension installation is same for php5.x and php7.x. Nothing much changes; unless the source conflicts with php7.x. Please try compiling manually from the source and let us know whether it helped. Else you have to contact the maintainer to check if present version supports php7.x https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu . Windows php7.x binary versions are already available for APCu

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.intro.php please check this as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625161/peclcommand-not-found similar error

Answer (score 32):

First, I'm assuming you installed PHP7 using the [DotDeb APT Repository](https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/). If not, this is how you should install it.

Once PHP7 is installed and working properly, and assuming there are no other versions of PHP installed on the system, install `apcu` via:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
pecl install apcu

echo "extension=apcu.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
```

Just press enter if prompted to specify any configuration.

Comment: David P's answer below (probably soon deleted, as it's really a comment) suggests that "acpu" should be "apcu" in various parts of your sample code.

Comment: I always get `...compilation terminated.
make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
` after `pecl install apcu`

Comment: `php7.0-dev` package must be installed for successful compile

Comment: The last echo line produces a permission denied with with sudo

Answer (score 20):

I know that this post is old but I would like to contrib with the way that works for me, because I tried the three answers in this question and I couldn't install APCU successfully. My problem with the answers wasn't the installation of APCU, `pecl install apcu` works and installed it. But I try to add the extension line in `php.ini` following each method, but neither of them works for me. I checked in a php file with `phpinfo()` and it always didn't show the APCU as installed extension.

After research more in the search results I found a easy way to install it in [WPBullet](https://guides.wp-bullet.com/install-apcu-object-cache-for-php7-for-wordpress-ubuntu-16-04/). What I did was to install the packages `php-apcu` and `php-apcu-bc` with:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-apcu
```

This works for me without manual writting in php.ini. Don't forget to restart apache2, or whatever you have as server.

Comment: I get `Unable to locate package php7.0-apcu` after an `apt-get update`.

Comment: @Andru, have you tried to install it separately both packages `php-apcu` and `php-apcu-bc`?

Comment: Or for php7.1, `sudo apt-get install php7.1-apcu`

Comment: Obvious, but just in case, for php 7.3 eventually becomes `sudo apt-get install php7.3-apcu` :)

Answer (score 10):

Run :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
pecl install apcu
```

Do not immediately add `extension=apcu.so` on `php.ini` without checking. `extension=apcu.so` should automatically get added on `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini`. You can run `php -i | grep app` to check or cat `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini`. If you load twice, you'll get :

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'apcu' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

This message is probably kept for older system :

```
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/apcu-5.1.5
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=apcu.so" to php.ini
```

I can not comment on the existing answer (point is less than 50). I got that PHP error, then found that file.

Answer (score 8):

Check **/etc/php/(version like 7.2)/cli/conf.d** directory and find **20-apcu.ini**. If you dont see it there, You need to install it. To install follow bellow command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-apcu
```

Now add bellow line in php.ini file if it is not there.

```
extension=apcu.so
```

Notice: for **php7.2**-apcu use your own php version. for example **php7.0-apcu**

After install restart your php7.**X**-fpm service if you are using nginx

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Now reload nginx

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

or reload apache, if you are using it:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 6):

Just installed APCu on a Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with PHP 7.0.3-2:

```
$ pecl install apcu
$  cat > /etc/php/mods-available/test.ini
; configuration for php apcu module
; priority=20
extension=apcu.so
$ ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/apcu.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-apcu.ini
$ service php7.0-fpm restart
```

**`phpinfo()` output:**

[image: phpinfo-apcu]

Answer (score 4):

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and php-fpm 7.4.
To install apcu:

```
apt install php-apcu
```

Comment: Works for Debian 10 and 11 too.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Since Ubuntu is a derivative of Debian, many of the commands are the same.

Answer (score 1):

for PHP7.3 use following commands

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-apcu -y

sudo service php7.3-fpm restart

sudo service apache2 restart
```